# How to change css in react in this example?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to move the ball to the point where the mouse clicks. The function is logging the X and Y but not moving the ball. What am I missing here?

Typescript react component

```
  const PlayArea = () => {
  let top = 'inherit';
  let left = 'inherit';
  
  document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    console.log((e.clientX + 25) + 'px')
    top = (e.clientY - 25) + "px";
    console.log(top)
    left = e.clientX - 25 + "px";
  });
  return (
    <>
      <div className="ball" style={{ transform: `top ${top}, left ${left}` }}></div>
    </>
  );
};

export default PlayArea;
```

css

```
.ball {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #0b8027; 
  position:absolute;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your `top` and `left` variables to state objects and update them on your click event callback.

```
const [mouse, setMouse] = useState({})

useEffect(() => {
  const event = (e) => {
    setMouse({ top: `${e.clientY - 25}px`, left: `${e.clientX - 25}px` 
  }
  document.addEventListener("click", event);
  });
  return () => document.removeEventListener("click", event)
}, [])

return (
    <>
      <div className="ball" style={{ top: mouse?.top, left: mouse?.left }}></div>
    </>
);
```

You don't need to `transform` your `top` and `left` style properties.  You set them directly, and the elements `position` will allow it to move to the location you give it.

It would also be best to add your event listener on component mount, and remove it when the component unmounts with useEffect and the cleanup function.

Comment: Thanks man it works now, I forgot about state, I was knee deep in the html for a few days now

Comment: Actually my dude, I made an edit that is important.  The previous example will cause a memory leak if the component unmounts, such as navigating to another route. I added `useEffect` for proper handling of the listener.

Answer (score 0):

In order to rerender the component you need to make use of the state.
Declare your top and left variable in state like below and add the enent listener once your component is mounted.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const PlayArea = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        left: 'inherit',
        top: 'inherit',
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            setState({ left: `${e.clientX - 25}px`, top: `${e.clientY - 25}px` });
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <div className="ball" style={{ transform: `top ${state.top}, left ${state.left}` }} />
        </>
    );
};

export default PlayArea;
```

As you are adding your event listener to the document object you need to have the `position: fixed` unless you have a relative class for the div you have created.

```
.ball {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #0b8027; 
  position:fixed;

}
```

Comment: But you have accepted another answer as correct answer.